# protractor: when does restartBrowserBetweenTests: true run?

Tags: testing, selenium, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

I have this setting: `restartBrowserBetweenTests: true` in my config file but it seems that the *restart runs after the `beforeEach`* instead of running before the `beforeEach`.

This is causing my tests to fail because I need to execute code in beforeEach before each spec.

Comment: Could you provide an example spec demonstrating the problem (probably with console.logs inside to see the order)? Also, which jasmine and protractor versions are you using? Thanks.